# Is it possible to set background-size of element to '100% auto' for every browser?

Tags: javascript, background-size

I created a `div` element and tried to change its `background-size` property to **100% auto**, but it didn't work (I'm currently using chrome 47). Why can't I do this? How can I fix it?

## **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxL5p1qc/1/)**

Example code above changes background-size properties of two elements to `auto 100%` and `100% auto`. My code prints

```
First element's background-size property after change: 
auto 100% - Matches with auto 100%


Second element's background-size property after change: 
100% - Does not match with 100% auto
```

Comment: Nice way of logging.

Comment: @Vohuman Thank you :)

Comment: Works in my browser (Firefox 45). This means that the answer isn't a very interesting one, probably a browser spec compliance bug.

Comment: @lleaff Thank you! I changed my question :)